# Thousands of dictionary entries passed to class objects, is this the proper, efficient way to do this?

Tags: python

I am creating thousands of objects and it is taking a few seconds (understandable). I wanted to make sure, as someone who recently moved from another language, less prominent, is this an efficient way to do create so many objects or is it a waste of resources?

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.exe = str(i['exe'])
        self.path = str(i['path'])
        self.name =  str(i['name'])
        self.longpath = str(i['longpath'])


    # exampled output times 3k 
    #  longpath: 'C:\\program files\\Steam\\common\\\\Half-Life\\hlds.exe'
    #   exe:  'hlds.exe'
    #   name: 'Half-Life Dedicated Server'
    #
    

#starts here from main file, passing a list of dictionaries
def constructor(gameLib):
    # create library objects,
    # using a list to keep track
    lib = []
    x = 0
    for i in gameLib:
        lib.append(Library(i))
        print(lib[x].exe)
        x = x + 1
    return lib


def callThings(lib):   
    print(lib[3].path)
    pass
```

Comment: Might be a better fit at stackexchange https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This could be improved by using a list comprehension, but probably the bottleneck is not in the creation of the objects...

Comment: Only thing that really sticks out to me is the `x=0` part, you can use `for x, i in enumerate(Library(i))`, but it won't improve performance

Comment: Are you sure the code shown is taking a few seconds, and not something else? Creation of a few thousand objects from dicts would normally be pretty fast.

Comment: to dani and stuart it is def something else upon review. @Nathan im curious, Ive read multiple places "python doesnt have a standard index" or something to that effect, and Ive used the enumerate once before but as I transition, seeing the integer while I learn dictionaries and lists tends to be helpful. it sounds like there isnt a downside, and its technically less bytes for (x+=1) than enumerate in x i lol. Help me understand, im sure theres a difference im missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the efficiency of the code, you have to think about readability of it. Also print statements usually are expensive. So I suggest this refactor

```
class Library:
    def __init__(self, game_lib):
        self.exe = str(game_lib['exe'])
        self.path = str(game_lib['path'])
        self.name =  str(game_lib['name'])
        self.longpath = str(game_lib['longpath'])

def constructor(game_lib):
    return [Library(lib) for lib in game_lib]

def call_things(lib):   
    print(lib[3].path)
```

Comment: thank you @soundwave this was well done, and I have adopted. the print was removed and took a lot of time off, and some delay was elsewhere as described above. thank you very much.